# Why does Peter mention women being frightened in 1 Peter 3:6?

Tags: 1-peter

1 Peter 3:5-6 NASB

> “For in this way in former times the holy women also, who hoped in God, used to adorn themselves, being submissive to their own husbands; just as Sarah obeyed Abraham, calling him Lord, and you have become her children if you do what is right without being frightened by any fear.”

What would women be frightened by in the context of this verse? Their husbands, God, or something else? What might have Sarah been frightened by, if she is named as the historical comparison? One example I can think of is when Abram tried to give her as a wife to pagan kings…is Peter implying she did the right thing in obeying his (later noted by God to be incorrect) choice?

Answer (score 2):

The verses before may give a hint.

> 1 Wives, in the same way submit yourselves to your own husbands so that, if any of them do not believe the word, they may be **won over without words by the behavior of their wives**,
>
> 2 **when they see the purity and reverence of your lives.**
>
> 3 Your beauty should not come from outward adornment, such as elaborate hairstyles and the wearing of gold jewelry or fine clothes.
>
> 4 Rather, it should be that of your **inner self, the unfading beauty of a gentle and quiet spirit**, which is of great worth in God’s sight.
>
> 5 For this is the way the **holy women** of the past who put their hope in God used to adorn themselves. They submitted themselves to their own husbands,
>
> 6 like Sarah, who obeyed Abraham and called him her lord.

> You are her daughters if you do what is right and do not give way to fear. (1 Peter 3:1-6 NIV)

The last sentence is intentional separated from vv3:6a, for it does not refer to Sarah, it refers to the holy women (vv3:5) their purity and reverence (vv3:2) is of great worth in God's sight (vv3:4). These women have husbands who do not believe in God, and they save their husbands not by their external beauty (vv3:3), but by their  unfading inner beauty (vv3:4) that they can won their husband to God without words (vv3:1). But before that, their husbands may be difficult to them, but do not fear and continue to do what is right (vv3:6), for the Lord is with them as the Lord is with Sarah.